# React useState updates multiple dropdown elements

Tags: css, reactjs

Using the following React component:

```
const [show, setshow] = useState(false);

const handleShow = () => {
  setshow(!show);
};
```

And CSS:

```
.show {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown_content {
  padding: 3px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #cc3e14;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

And considering the following `<ul>` Html block:

```
return (
...
<ul>
  <li>
    <button onClick={() => handleShow()} className={styles.dropbtn}>File</button>
    <div id="file" className={styles.dropdown_content + (show ? " " + styles.show : "")}>
      <div className={styles.dropdown_content_inner}>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onClick={() => handleShow()} className={styles.dropbtn}>Edit</button>
    <div id="edit" className={styles.dropdown_content + (show ? " " + styles.show : "")}>
      <div className={styles.dropdown_content_inner}>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onClick={() => handleShow()} className={styles.dropbtn}>View</button>
    <div id="view" className={styles.dropdown_content + (show ? " " + styles.show : "")}>
      <div className={styles.dropdown_content_inner}>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button onClick={() => handleShow()} className={styles.dropbtn}>Help</button>
    <div id="help" className={styles.dropdown_content + (show ? " " + styles.show : "")}>
      <div className={styles.dropdown_content_inner}>
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
);
```

Results in all dropdown_content menu's to open if I click one. I struggle what I need to adjust to make the one menu open that I clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using a single show state for all dropdowns. To fix this, you need to manage the show state separately for each dropdown. Try adding separate states and handlers.

```js
const [showFile, setShowFile] = useState(false)
const [showEdit, setShowEdit] = useState(false)
const [showView, setShowView] = useState(false)
const [showHelp, setShowHelp] = useState(false)

const handleShowFile = () => {
 setShowFile(!showFile)
}

const handleShowEdit = () => {
 setShowEdit(!showEdit)
}

const handleShowView = () => {
 setShowView(!showView)
}

const handleShowHelp = () => {
 setShowHelp(!showHelp)
}
```

or may be something like this,

```js
const [showDropdowns, setShowDropdowns] = useState({
 file: false,
 edit: false,
 view: false,
 help: false,
})

const handleShowDropdown = (dropdown) => {
 setShowDropdowns((prevState) => ({
   ...prevState,
   [dropdown]: !prevState[dropdown],
 }))
}
```

Then use the states and handlers accordingly within your list elements.

Comment: Thanks! The first solution works for me. The second solution did not work, although it looks better.